# How to do clustering of JSON document?

Tags: json, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

Java script object notation documents are getting popular these days ,nosql database like MongoDB uses JSON but search query takes lots of time in this case as compared to Relational Database Management System so I am thinking of clustering JSON documents(It should be noted that two JSON documents in the same cluster should have same order of attributes) which will ultimately help to speed up searching time.
As we know that XML is similar to JSON but it has explicit schema ,so clustering can be done on XML documents by means of structural-constraints or semantic clustering techniques.Current state of the art for XML clustering are XC-NMF(clustering by non-negative matrix factorization), X Co-clustering(uses matrix tri factorization) and XPath(uses transactional clustering).

I think JSON documents needs some kind of structure ,maybe if I am able to represent JSON in a form of tree then I maybe able to extract feature from the documents.

Any idea of how to approach this problem will help me a lot? I want to know how to represent JSON documents to vector and perform clustering.

Answer (score -1):

JSON has a well-defined tree representation.

So many such approaches will work.

*You* just have to define good features.